# C++ segmentation fault issue

Tags: c++

If anyone is able to help and tell me why it segfaults, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

**Note**: I'm not allowed to modify the `main` function by any means.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <list>
#include <cmath>

class Object {
 public:
 private:
  float d;

 public:
  Object(float n) : d(n) {}
  Object() {}

  struct PointType {
    float x2;
    float y2;
    PointType(float x1, float y1) : x2(x1), y2(y1) {}
    PointType() {}
    float x() { return x2; }
    float y() { return y2; }
    PointType center() { return *this; }
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const PointType &p) {
      os << p;

      return os;
    }
  };

  virtual void render() const {}
  virtual ~Object() {}
};

class Point : public Object {
 private:
  PointType mpoint;

 public:
  Point(const PointType &pt, float &y1) : Object(y1), mpoint(pt) {}
  Point(const PointType &pt) : mpoint(pt) {}
  Point() {}

  Point center() const { return *this; }
  float x() { return mpoint.x2; }
  float y() { return mpoint.y2; }
  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Point &p) {
    os << p.center();
    return os;
  }
};

class VisiblePoint : public Point {
 public:
  VisiblePoint(const Object::PointType &point) : Point(point) {}

  void render() const override {
    std::cout << "Point at " << center() << std::endl;
  }
};

// A simple pseudo-random number generator.
class PseudoRandom {
  const int A = 101;
  const int B = 919;
  const int C = 10619863;

  int _current;

 public:
  PseudoRandom() : _current(0) {}

  int operator()() {
    _current = (A * _current + B) % C;
    _current += (_current < 0) ? C : 0;
    return _current;
  }

  int operator()(int n) { return (*this)() % n; }

  float operator()(float a, float b) {
    int result = (*this)();
    return a + (b - a) * static_cast<float>(result) / float(C);
  }
};

int main() {
  std::list<Object *> objects;
  PseudoRandom random;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    switch (random(1)) {
      case 0: {
        const Object::PointType point(random(0, 1), random(0, 1));
        objects.push_back(new VisiblePoint(point));
        break;
      }
      case 1: {
      }
      case 2: {
      }
      case 3: {
      }
      case 4: {
      }
    }
  }
  std::cout << "BEGIN" << std::endl;

  std::for_each(objects.begin(), objects.end(), std::mem_fn(&Object::render));

  std::cout << "END" << std::endl;

  for (const Object *object : objects) {
    delete object;
  }
  objects.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a stack overflow because of

> ```
> friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& p)
> {
>    os << p.center(); 
>    return os;
> }
> ```

calling itself without ending because `Point::center()` returns a *Point* (*center* just return the instance)

You have the same stack overflow problem for *PointType*, you can change these definition to have for instance :

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& p)
{
    os << p.mpoint; 
    return os;
}

friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const 
        PointType& p)
{   
    os << "x=" << p.x2 << ", y=" << p.y2;
    return os;              
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -g -pedantic -Wextra -Wall c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
BEGIN
Point at x=0.00882667, y=0.89158
Point at x=0.015971, y=0.613159
Point at x=0.845152, y=0.360472
Point at x=0.186335, y=0.819929
Point at x=0.108734, y=0.982257
Point at x=0.0107827, y=0.0891412
Point at x=0.337889, y=0.126905
Point at x=0.567967, y=0.364747
Point at x=0.788968, y=0.685901
Point at x=0.889105, y=0.799651
END
```

Note the member *d* is private in *Object* and there is no way to access it (nor to write it), if I add

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Object & o) {
  os << "d=" << o.d;
  return os;
}
```

and modify the `operator<<` for *Point* to have :

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& p)
{
    os << p.mpoint << ", ";
    os << (const Object &) p;
    return os;
}
```

and initialize *d* in the default constructor of *Object* :

```
Object() : d(0) {}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -g -pedantic -Wextra -Wall c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
BEGIN
Point at x=0.00882667, y=0.89158, d=0
Point at x=0.015971, y=0.613159, d=0
Point at x=0.845152, y=0.360472, d=0
Point at x=0.186335, y=0.819929, d=0
Point at x=0.108734, y=0.982257, d=0
Point at x=0.0107827, y=0.0891412, d=0
Point at x=0.337889, y=0.126905, d=0
Point at x=0.567967, y=0.364747, d=0
Point at x=0.788968, y=0.685901, d=0
Point at x=0.889105, y=0.799651, d=0
END
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: Hi @bruno, thanks. However, I am still facing the seg fault issue after adding std::endl to both. Any other ideas why?

Comment: @starrk the problem is not the _endl_, the problem is `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& p)` calls itself recursively  without ending so you fill the stack up to its overflow. I edited my answer , reread it

Comment: Hi @bruno, thanks a lot for the detailed explanation! best in biz. But why does returning an instance in center() keeps calling itself as compared to returning a point since the main() wanted the center... Do you mind elaborating on it further? i didn't understand.

Comment: @starrk a point is its center because a point does not have width/height. Are you sure you do not want the center of a line or a rectangle etc so the center of a form defined from several points ?. (I also edited again my answer to write _d_)

Comment: @starrk in case of a polygon probably the operator<< has to write all the points defining it no ? Warning a polygon **does not** inherit _Point,_ but a polygon as a member like `std::vector<Point> points;` for instance

Comment: u are absolutely right. Unfortunately, my school decided that that would not be the case and told us to do polygon inherits from point. I know.

Comment: @starrk are you sure of that ? That has non sense at all :-( I think you do not well understand

Comment: I did not misread or misinterpret them. In fact I already asked them.

Comment: Hence, why I get stuck sometimes. Coz it all defying logic lol. I have been implementing just based off on the main() file itself without really understanding although I try.

Comment: @starrk polygon can inherits Object, but not Point

Comment: the functions I can understand. But the inheritance part is the worst. They even asked to inherit square from circle.

Comment: @starrk move to an other school ^^

Comment: Ahahaha. I really do not know what their intention is.. but I just go along with it. School fees been paid.

Comment: Oh man. I am getting another seg fault from the polygon class as well. kill me now.

Comment: @starrk run your program into a debugger to see if it is again a stack overflow and where

Comment: Oh man. I hate stack overflow( not this website->been a life saver for me). Anyways, thanks a lot for the help:) Is there anyway we could keep in touch? Hahaha

Comment: @starrk the best place to keep in touch is here because you can find more people than me, including better than me ;-)